# Flutter, How to put UI onto the button?

Tags: user-interface, button, flutter, uibutton

```
  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed:() {
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                          );
                        },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        )
                    )
                      ))]),
```

As you can see from the code, the UI Login Container is in front of the button but the dimensions are very off. Is there anyway I can bundle this all together?

Comment: Could you show the preview (UI) of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold()),
          );
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?
[image]
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIjbO.png)

```
FlatButton(
      child: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
        );
      },
    ),
```